# Getting Error While Iterating on JSON Array using for:each in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

We have data as below in track variable `rowColorRules` :

```
[{
    "color": "#ED0E0E",
    "criterias": [{
        "field": "sdd",
        "operator": "==",
        "value": "asdads"
    },{
        "field": "sdd",
        "operator": "==",
        "value": "asdads"
    }],
    "upArrow": false,
    "downArrow": false
}]
```

So, here `rowColorRules` is array and `criterias` within each `rowColorRules` is also array and we are trying to iterate nested `for:each` withing main `for:each`
But in `for:each` of `criterias` we are getting below errors:

[image]

HTML code is as below:

```
<template for:each={rowColorRules} for:item="rule" for:index="index">
    <!-- some html -->
    <template for:each={rule.criterias} for:item="criteria">
        <!-- some html -->
    </template>
</template>
```

If i will remove for loop of `criterias` then it will start working perfectly.

Comment: It should not throw error - can you show full code?

Comment: You should have a key field that is unique for each iteration item.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried from my end in LWC playground. I am not getting any error

```
@track test = [{
    "color": "#ED0E0E",
    "criterias": [{
        "field": "sdd",
        "operator": "==",
        "value": "asdads"
    },{
        "field": "sdd",
        "operator": "==",
        "value": "asdads"
    }],
    "upArrow": false,
    "downArrow": false
}]

    <template>
        <template for:each={test} for:item="rule" for:index="index"> 
            <template for:each={rule.criterias} for:item="criteria">
              {criteria.operator}
            </template>
        </template>
    </template>
```

Comment: Actually there are 2 component and this JSON is part of parent component and child is calling CustomEvent and passing some data to parent, parent will alter the JSON. After that It should refresh the view (html renderer). But i am getting the error. @learningmode It is working first time when component will load.